# address space Library or Process

Tags: c, linux, memory, shared-libraries

I have one basic doubt.
I have a process which uses a shared library. If I am allocating some memory in the library
then which address space it is. (Library or Process) 
In my opinion it is the process address space because once the library is attached it is all in process address space.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks
Arpit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A library doesn't have its own address space. It is mapped into and executed within some process. So you are right. Memory allocations of a shared library are done inside the process which is using it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are may be getting confused between address space and heap.

A process has a single address space and everything within the a process (the main executable, any shared libraries and any static libraries) all share the single address space.

While it's possible for there to be multiple heaps in a single address space, glibc is implemented in such a way that there is only one standard heap (by standard heap, I mean the one you access via malloc/free).  This is different from Windows where the executable and dll's may each have their own heap (although again, the share a single address space).

Answer (score 1):

A library has no memory space on its own as it is not a running process.   The concept of a shared library is to have shared copy of the code instructions but not of any data used or generated by that code.

so for example if your library is designed to manage a dynamically allocated structure:

*object.h*

```
 struct object_struct {
        char *name; 
        int foo;
        int bar;
 };

 typedef struct object_struct * object_t; /* opaque pointer */

 object_t new_object (char *name, int foo, int bar);
 void delete_object(object_t);
 int dump_object(object_t);
```

*object.c*

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include "object.h"    

  object_t new_object (char *_name, int foo, int bar) {
       object_t _p = malloc(sizeof(object_t);
       if (!_p) 
             return NULL;
       _p->foo = foo; _p->bar = bar;
       _p->name = strdup(_name);
       return _p;
  } 

  void delete_object(object_t p) {
       if(_p->name) 
          free(_p->name);

       if(_p) 
           free(_p);
  }

  int dump_object(object_t p) {
       FILE * fp = fopen(p->name, "w");
       if ( !fp ) 
            return -1;
       fprintf(fp, "foo: %d\nbar: %d\n", p->foo, p->bar);
       fclose(fp);
       return 0;
  }
```

And you have two programs consumer1.c and consumer2.c that use that library object as under:

*consumer1.c*

```
 #include "object.h"

 int main() {
      object_t o = new_object("consumer1.txt", 1, 2);
      dump_object(o);
      delete_object(o);
      return 0;
 }
```

*consumer2.c*

```
 #include "object.h"

 int main() {
      object_t o = new_object("consumer2.txt", 1, 2);
      dump_object(o);
      delete_object(o);
      return 0;
 }
```

for all intents and purposes, these two programs of the object library WILL NOT have any common data or common memory or common space.

P.S.: assuming gcc and gnu make, here is a make file for you to test it all out.

*Makefile*

```
default: libobject.a consumer1 consumer2

.c.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

libobject.a: object.o
    $(AR) r $@ object.o


object.o: object.c object.h

consumer1 consumer2: $@.o libobject.a
    $(CC) -o $@ $@.o -L. -lobject
```

P.P.S: This is presented as JUST a guide! I haven't tested the code here AT ALL, hopefully it all works without a hitch however, take it with a grain of salt and if i've made syntactical error please fix appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

A shared library can link with many processes and it is run in the context of those processes.

Say you have a shared library to send http request. A browser process and a desktop application can both link with that library but the process context will enable them to send independent requests despite both having loaded the same library.

Hence process context determines the allocation of memory no matter where it is written(process or library).